# How to calculate ActualWidth ActualHeight before window showing

Tags: .net, wpf, window, measure, actualwidth

I'm trying to calculate `StackPanel` `width`, `height` (located in middle cell of the grid) before window showing (for example in window constructor). How it can be achieved?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="stackPanel"></StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Measure for Window also as for stackPanel sets `DesiredSize` to `{0;0}`

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Measure(new Size(this.Width, this.Height)); // -> this.DesiredSize = {0;0}

        ...

    }
}
```

EDIT1

The following works for FixedPage:

```
fixedPage.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); 
fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, fixedPage.DesiredSize.Width, fixedPage.DesiredSize.Height));
```

Then we can access `stackPanel.ActualWidth` and `stackpanel.ActualHeight`.

But for the Window, it does not works.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Loaded` event:

```
public TestWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(TestWindow_Loaded);
}

void TestWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //this.DesiredSize shouldnt be {0,0} now
}
```

**EDIT:** Due to the fact, that a `StackPanel` already takes the maximum `Size`, even with no items in it, its `SizeChanged` event will only be fired if you add to much items, so you can use the `SizeChanged` event of your `StackPanel` like this:

```
private void spTest_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.PreviousSize.Height == 0 && e.PreviousSize.Width == 0)) //will also be fired after loading
    {
        //Create another Page
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:** Another possible solution:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    yourStackPanelName.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(yourStackPanelName_Loaded);
}

void yourStackPanelName_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double height = ((StackPanel)sender).ActualHeight;
    double width = ((StackPanel)sender).ActualWidth;
}
```

Comment: It's suitable for Window but Window here is only for example. I need to place Grid into FixedPage and I must find the dimentions of the stackPanel as a content zone for this page - it helps to answer how many items I can put in it ... For each item I define Mesure and now it's height and then I reached end of page I need to create another Page and so on ....

Comment: Why do you need to set the StackPanel's height and width? A Stackpanel without items always takes the height and the width of its parents area, so you dont need to set these by code.

Comment: I want GET height and width not SET and as asked befor I need this to find out posible items count in stackPanel. If I put more items in it they will be invisible in FixedPage

Comment: thank's but it's not suitable for me .... each time then you scroll DocumentViewer to FixedPage with Loaded event it will be executed ...

Comment: Maybe you should post more code of your programm, so that we know what's suitable for you.

Comment: for FixedPage solution is: 1st run fixedPage.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); 2nd fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, fixedPage.DesiredSize.Width, fixedPage.DesiredSize.Height)); 3d access stackPanel.ActualWidth stackpanel.ActualHeight for WINDOW it does not works